# Unity c# Inheritance / generic Interface to upgrade different subclasses

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface

I am trying to upgrade a specific cannon, by using an interface, the problem I am facing is that for some reason the functions are being called correctly and there are no errors, but in fact the parameteres are not "upgraded" as expected.

```
BaseWeapon.cs

public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{

public new string name;
public int level = 1;
public int damage;
public int cost;
private BaseEnemy target;
public IDoDamage damageType;
public IDoUpgrade upgradeType;

public int TryDoDamage(BaseEnemy target, int damage)
{
    this.target = target;
    int dmg = (int)damageType?.DoDamage(target, damage);
    target.UpdateHealth();
    return dmg;
}
public void TryDoUpgrade(BaseCannon cannon)
{
    Debug.Log("Inside TryDoUpgrade SUCCESS");    // This debug works
    upgradeType?.DoUpgrade(cannon);
    Island.Instance.Spend(cannon.cost);
}
```

The above debug works, and gold is subtracted from the player as expected.

`DefCannon.cs` I use this to instantiate a `BaseCannon` that inherits from `BaseWeapon`, with custom parameters, this is the default cannon, I also have a `FireCannon` as an example, they all inherit from `BaseCannon`, which in turn inherits from `BaseWeapon`.:

```
public class DefCannon : BaseCannon
{
public void Init(int level)
{
    name = "Defcannon";
    this.level = level;
    cannonMat = Cannonballs.cbCannonMat["Default"];
    damage = 50 * level;
    ballMat = Cannonballs.cbMat["Default"];
    cbSpeed = Cannonballs.cbSpeed["Default"];
    minPrecision = 0.91f;
    maxPrecision = 1.11f;
    minReload = 0.5f;
    maxReload = 1.0f;
    damageType = new DefDamage(level);
    upgradeType = new DefUpgrade(this, level);
}
}
```

I think the problem might be here aswell  `upgradeType = new DefUpgrade(this, level);`

```
this = DefCannon.cs // which inherits from BaseCannon
```

However `DefUpgrade(BaseCannon baseCannon, int level)` DefUpgrade is asking for a `BaseCannon`, instead we give it a child of `BaseCannon` in this case that is `DefCannon`, might this be the reason why its not working? and how would I solve this, I dont have a reference to the `BaseCannon` script from the child script, is there a way to do `this.BaseCannon`, (calling the parent class somehow?)

To clarify, the above script is only used to set the parameters, I have a prefabCannon, with no scripts, when I instatiate that prefabCannon, I add the script `DefCannon` or `FireCannon`, depending on which cannon I want to Instantiate, this way I can have them all use the generic functions they would all need, but have custom paramters and such for each one as well.

`DefUpgrade.cs` This is were the problem is, the `Debug.Log` in the BaseWeapon script works, but the next step it takes when it enters into `DefUpgrade.cs` and tries to call `DoUpgrade()` fails, because there `Debug.Log` in that script is never called:

```
public class DefUpgrade : IDoUpgrade
{
public int level;
public DefUpgrade(BaseCannon baseCannon, int level)
{
    this.level = level;
    baseCannon.cost = DefUpgradeDictionary.cost[level];
}
public void DoUpgrade(BaseCannon baseCannon)
{
    Debug.Log("Inside DoUpgrade SUCCESS");   // This debug is never reached/called
    var baseDamage = baseCannon.damage / baseCannon.level;
    baseCannon.level++;
    baseCannon.damage = baseDamage * level;
    var lvl = baseCannon.level;
    baseCannon.damageType = new DefDamage(lvl);       //CHECK IF IT WORKS
    baseCannon.minPrecision = DefUpgradeDictionary.minPrecision[lvl];
    baseCannon.maxPrecision = DefUpgradeDictionary.maxPrecision[lvl];
    baseCannon.minReload = DefUpgradeDictionary.minReload[lvl];
    baseCannon.maxReload = DefUpgradeDictionary.maxReload[lvl];
    baseCannon.cost = DefUpgradeDictionary.cost[lvl];

}
}
```

I used the exact same interface structure to do damage, as all cannons need to do damage, but again with different params, in that structure I have no issues, but as I recreated it for Upgrades it doesnt seem to work but what makes this so confusing is that there are no console errors, no missing references, it debugs function A that then calls function B, but the debug in function B then never gets called!

IDoUpgrade.cs interface

```
public interface IDoUpgrade
{
    void DoUpgrade(BaseCannon cannon);
}
```

Calling `TryDoUpgrade()`

```
baseCannon = PlayerRays.Instance.baseCannon;
    if (PlayerRays.Instance.safe && Island.Instance.gold >= baseCannon.cost)
    {
        PlayerRays.Instance.baseWeapon.TryDoUpgrade(baseCannon);
        
    }
```

These last 2 scripts work fine, the problem doesnt seem to be there.

Thank you for looking into this I appreciate it a lot as ive been trying to figure this out for almost 2 days now.

Update1: Added BaseCannon.cs:

```
public class BaseCannon : BaseWeapon
{
    private Transform cannon, cylinder, spawn, closestEnemy;
    private MeshRenderer mesh;
    private GameObject flame;
    private List<Transform> enemyShips;
    public Material cannonMat, ballMat;
    public float cbSpeed;
    private float aliveTime = 15f;
    public float minPrecision, maxPrecision, minReload, maxReload;

    void Start()
    {
        cannon = transform.Find("Cannon");
        cylinder = cannon.transform.Find("Cylinder");
        spawn = cylinder.transform.Find("Spawn");
        flame = spawn.transform.Find("Flame").gameObject;
        flame.SetActive(false);
        mesh = cannon.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mesh.material = cannonMat;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess we are missing your code for `BaseCannon` ...

Comment: `instead we give it a child of BaseCannon` .. it's not a "child", your `DefCannon` **is** a `BaseCannon` just with some additional fields/methods etc .. unless it **hides** a member (having one with the same name as the base class without using `override`) there should be no reason why it behaves different

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply DerHugo.DefCannon doesnt hide anything, only initializes the values, but ive added the BaseCannon Script as you askeed :)

Comment: What I really need to figure out is why `upgradeType?.DoUpgrade(cannon);` in BaseWeapon gets called, but then is never executed and also doesnt throw any null reference exceptions in the console either.

Comment: Well `upgradeType?.DoUpgrade(cannon);` basically is a shorthand for `if(upgradeType != null) upgradeType.DoUpgrade(cannon);` so it's entire purpose is to prevent a `NullReferenceException` but doesn't do anything if the `upgradeType` is `null` ... Are you sure `DefCannon.Init` has been called?

Comment: Also why in `TryDoUpdate` you pass in the `BaseCannon` as parameter? That doesn't look right since you basically already operate on an instance of `BaseWeapon` so it should probably rather take this is parameter and do `upgradeType?.DoUpgrade(this);`

Comment: I can confirm `upgradeType.DoUpgrade(this);` this retuns a null reference exception even though the `upgradeType` gets initialized in the `DefCannon` script, just like the `damageType` does. maybe I should initialize the `upgradeType` again before calling it...

Comment: DAMN IT i fixed it. it works like a charm now.    `cannon.upgradeType.DoUpgrade(cannon);`    this fixed it, instead of calling the damagtype on the baseweapon just call it on the basecannon we just gave it, and also input that same one in again, it seems a bit circular could need some refactoring but it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I believe is in the BaseWeapon class. (If I understand the structure correctly)  You're passing in the BaseCannon which has the upgradeType defined in it, but you're calling the method from the BaseWeapon.

```
public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{

public new string name;
public int level = 1;
...
public IDoUpgrade upgradeType;


public void TryDoUpgrade(BaseCannon cannon)
{
    Debug.Log("Inside TryDoUpgrade SUCCESS");    // This debug works
    upgradeType?.DoUpgrade(cannon);
    
    // in fact the upgrade is null as it's defined in the cannon
    // not the weapon. 
    if (upgradeType == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("No upgrade defined. Create from cannon");
        // set the upgrade from the cannon, and then call it
        upgradeType = cannon.upgradeType;
        upgradeType?.DoUpgrade(cannon);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice catch! I was figuring this out in the comment thread above together with derhugo in the meantime i missed your answer but you are 100% correct sir. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is working `int dmg = (int)damageType?.DoDamage(target, damage);` Its calling the method from baseweapon even though it is defined by baseCannon instead, just like `DoUpgrade`

Comment: Hard to say without seeing that code, but you don't pass in the BaseCannon in for the DoDamage method so I'm assuming it's called on the cannon prefab itself.

In answer to one of your other points above, you can always cast to a base class in the 'child' as you refer to it.  E.g. in BaseCannon
   BaseWeapon bw = (BaseWeapon)theCannon;
...but it's really the same object just with extra methods you can access by the inherited object. So if you defined a DoDomage in the 'child'...cast to the BaseClass you would still be calling that same DoDamage method.